# Bold code in rst

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How can I get code (monospace) text that is bold in rst (I'm using Sphinx)? Anything in `::` seems to be rendered literally, as with ``, so ``**bold**`` doesn't work.

Comment: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible

Comment: @mzjn I think the raw html directive is the ticket. Add that as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, nested inline markup is [not possible in reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible). There are more or less ugly workarounds, such as using [raw](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) HTML. Like this:

```
.. raw:: html

   <div>Some stuff <pre>some <b>bold</b> text</pre>...</div>
```

Comment: This may require adding some css classes to the blocks to get the right formatting (e.g., `<pre>` in this way renders differently than code in \`\`), and it's hacky, but it works!

Answer (score 2):

Actually using `raw` for code is a very bad thing to do as it ignores the beautiful Pygments highlighting and complicates things to extreme. First thing to do is to play with different Pygments highlighting styles. You can find a functional demo [here](http://pygments.org/demo/). Then you may set the appropriate highlighting in `conf.py`. If none of the styles make the desired part of your code bold, you may consider creating your own Pygments theme, which is unfamiliar territory for me, but shouldn't be that hard.

There is third thing to try though, you could look up the class of the word you need to highlight and add a rule to your CSS. Pygments produce this seemingly gibberish classes like `nv`, `ls`, etc for every type of the highlighted words. But keep in mind, that every instance of this type will be highlighted. If your chosen word is a class definition - all class definitions will be highlighted.

Only if none of these options apply should you consider using something as atrocious as `raw`, because every time someone uses `raw`, Sphinx dies a little. Do you really want Sphinx to die?

Comment: For my use-case it's not something that gets syntax highlighted, so this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely restructured text does not support formatting options you are asking for.

However you are free to add your own `::` admonition directives which have custom CSS styling over them.

Example for a custom block and CSS styling. RST:

```
 .. admonition:: foobar

         My custom text here
```

CSS:

```
.admonition-foobar {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't want the whole thing to be bold, though. I want the equivalent of `<pre>some <b>bold</b> text</pre>` in html.

Comment: That would probably need writing a custom syntax highlighter and have your own "code" for `code-block ::`.